# Get BlockNumber from Pallet

Tags: frame-system, blocknumber

I have `struct` that holds when it's created as `BlockNumber`.

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Clone, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(BlockTime, MaxContentLength))]
pub struct Listing<BlockNumber, MaxContentLength: Get<u32>> {
    pub is_active: bool,
    pub content: Content<MaxContentLength>,
    pub created: BlockNumber,
    pub updated: Option<BlockNumber>,
}
```

And I'm trying to set it like this but getting an error saying type argument `T` not allowed.

```rust
Listings::<T>::insert(
    &property,
    &who,
    Listing {
        is_active: is_active.unwrap_or(false),
        content,
        created: frame_system::<T>::Pallet::current_block_number(),
        updated: None,
    },
);
```

```
error[E0109]: type arguments are not allowed for this type
  --> pallets/listing/src/lib.rs:87:30
   |
87 |                     created: frame_system::<T>::Pallet::current_block_number(),
   |                                             ^ type argument not allowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0109`.
error: could not compile `pallet-listing` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Listings::<T>::insert(
    &property,
    &who,
    Listing {
        is_active: is_active.unwrap_or(false),
        content,
        created: frame_system::Pallet::<T>::current_block_number(),
        updated: None,
    },
);
```

Comment: That was a silly mistake, ^^. Thanks for the answer